# Прескриптивизм в быту.

Tags: грамотная-речь

Почему многие люди, владеющие основами литературной нормы, считают нужным предписывать её окружающим?

В случае нарушения литературной нормы многие говорят о мнимом «вымирании» языка, но разве диахроническое изменение языка (и, значит, как узуса, так и литературной нормы) не является чем-то, с одной стороны, обыденным, а с другой — неизбежным?

Следует ли считать хорошим, что некоторые люди довольно агрессивно встречают несоблюдение литературной нормы в быту, считают её «лучше» узуса? Ведь «стандартный» язык предназначен, насколько мне известно, вовсе не для всех ситуаций, в которых такие люди проявляют подобную агрессивность.

Насколько вообще далеко следует заходить с лингвистическим прескриптивизмом в различных условиях, в разговоре с носителями русского языка различных социальных слоёв и т. п.?

Заранее спасибо за ответ! С уважением, школьник.

Comment: Всё-таки кто может что-то сказать по теме? Мне интересны все мнения!

Answer (score 2):

Ну вы же понимаете, что всё зависит от ситуации.
Человека, который встречает замечания c благодарностью, можно и нужно поправлять.
Или ребенка. 
А от товарища прапорщика, который отправляет "грузить люминь", лучше держаться подальще.
Чуковский, говорят, от детей был рад выслушать всё, а услышав от взрослого что-нибудь наподобие "Я броюсь", уходил не попрощавшись.
Я обычно не поправляю, поскольку большинство современных мужчин ближе к прапорщику.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Отличный ответ, здорово, behemotus!

Answer (score 1):

Прескр**и**птивизм, а не прескр**е**птивизм.

Comment: Я идиот.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Самокритичный школьник! Ну уже то, что знаешь такие слова, грамотно расставляешь знаки препинания, характеризует тебя ка человека, довольно грамотного, а вот комментарий - как не очень воспитанного. Хотя и Завада мог (или могла) бы сделать замечание покорректнее. Вообще, конечно же, не стоит говорить о вымирании русского языка. Я согласна, что литературные нормы постоянно меняются.Те же диалектные слова, вроде ПЛЕТНЯ - уже стали общеупотребительными. Другой разговор, что подразумевается под ненормативной лексикой. Если молодёжный сленг, то все, даже самые рьяные поборники за чистоту русского языка, будучи студентами (если были), использовали ненормативную лексику в своей речи. Да и смешно, наверное, было бы, если бы в неофициальной обстановке, в кругу друзей, сверстников говорили бы только так, как записано в Орфоэпическом словаре. Другой разговор, если жаргонизмы, арготизмы, бранные слова школьники употребляют на уроках, в общественных местах, в присутствии людей, которые им в отцы, а то и деды годятся, или на работу пришли устраиваться, а нормально и слова сказать не могут, то это просто говорит о полном бескультурии и языковой безграмотности. Ну и для меня абсолютно недопустимо, когда молодой человек называет свою девушку, например, "моя тёлка", "гирла" и прочее... Здесь не может и речи быть о каких-то чувствах, а полнейшее неуважение к своей девушке. Ну а уж если девушка на подобные высказывания в свой адрес весело хихикает, то это тоже полное неуважение к себе или - кретинизм.

Comment: С какой стати Вадимий — "не очень воспитанный"? "Поборники за чистоту" — не по-русски. Не о полном бескультурИИ, а о полном бескультурЬЕ. Перед "на подобные высказывания" надо было написать "в ответ".

Comment: Я бы не стал смешивать просторечия и неправильные формы с моложежным, например сленгом. К последнему я отношусь вполне терпимо. Но вопрос, насколько понимаю, именно о просторечиях.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Спасибо за "бескультурье", здесь я с Вами полностью согласна, ошиблась. "Поборники за чистоту" следовало взять в кавычки, так как такое высказывание слышишь довольно часто. А вот о последнем - именно "в свой адрес", т. е., когда девушка со смехом воспринимает то, что о ней говорят.